# Azure Function in Isolated Mode: How to build a Docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, azure-functions, .net-5

I am trying to build a Function App running on `.net5` in a Docker container. As of now, I am simply trying to build the project.

Here is the `dockerfile` I have so far:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY "src/" "source/"

RUN dotnet restore "source/StorageManager/StorageManager.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "source/StorageManager"
RUN dotnet build "StorageManager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 4.21 sec).
  WorkerExtensions -> /tmp/efutopu1.pad/buildout/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found. [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :   - The following frameworks were found: [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :       5.0.9 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App] [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : The specified framework can be found at: [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :   - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64 [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error :  [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]
/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): error : Metadata generation failed. [/tmp/efutopu1.pad/WorkerExtensions.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

**Question**

I do not understand what is happening. It seems like `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll` package requires something more that just the `.net5` runtime but I am not sure exactly what to do. Should I use one of the following image

`https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base`

or

`https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated`

Answer (score 0):

**Update---**

Build requires 3.1 SDK. In your `Dockerfile` add the following lines after the first FROM statement:

```
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
```

**later..**

after below you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=isolated-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp#push-the-image-to-docker-hub) or simply [this](https://dev.to/codeprototype/azure-function-app-and-docker-on-azure-made-easy-in-12-steps-3fob) to deploy the app to container.

You can use [Azure Functions Dotnet (Isolated) by Microsoft | Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-dotnet-isolated)

After [configuring your local environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=isolated-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp#tabpanel_1_isolated-process), from the root project folder, run the  [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)  command, and provide a name,  `azurefunctionsimage`, and tag,  `v1.0.0`. Replace  `<DOCKER_ID>`  with your Docker Hub account ID. This command builds the Docker image for the container.

```
docker build --tag <DOCKER_ID>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0 .
```

When the command completes, you can run the new container locally.

To test the build, run the image in a local container using the  [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)  command, replacing again  `<DOCKER_ID`  with your Docker ID and adding the ports argument,  `-p 8080:80`:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -it <docker_id>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
```

After the image starts in the local container, browse to  `http://localhost:8080/api/HttpExample`, which should display the same greeting message as before. Because the HTTP triggered function you created uses anonymous authorization, you can call the function running in the container without having to obtain an access key.

Before you can deploy your function code to Azure, you need to create three resources: checkout  [Create supporting Azure resources for your function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=isolated-process,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-csharp#create-supporting-azure-resources-for-your-function)

Comment: The answer is a bit vague to me and does not seem specific enough for the question. I am interested in putting the proper statements in the docker file that will use both the azurefunctionimage and build / include my function app as well... I do not see this in the answer :(

Comment: I have updated few that require during build, further you can follow docs which have examples extensively.

Comment: I have not made much progress on this. The documentation to build containers in general does exist. However the documentation on how to create a dockerfile to build and containerize a Function App running in Isolated Mode is pretty scarse...

Comment: please update once you find a solution. This can be beneficial to other community members.